# Implementing VOIP over udp, what is the approach to take when the player cannot cope up with received packet's speed

Tags: android, audio, udp, voip, rtp

I am implementing p2p voice over IP on android, using UDP, openSL and some audio compression.
The voice chat works good when 2 peers are connected, and the lag is steadily about 100ms.
When a third peer connects, one or more peer progressively accumulate lag, reaching 15+ seconds in some cases.

My guess is that for some reason processing speed can't cope up with the receiving speed (packets gets accumulated in the audio buffer).
What is the correct approach to take in this case?
Should I discard some packets so that the lag goes back to a small value?

I don't think I have a problem with the application implementation, I have one thread for UDP receiving (no sleep, only I/O) and enqueuing audio for play, one for voice recording and UDP transmission(no sleep, only I/O) and some other threads that do unrelated things.
Is this a common situation in VOIP, or is there a problem with this design?

EDIT:
I was previously mixing the sound with OpenSL, but now I switched to the simpler android API which seems to alleviate the problem but does not solve it.

This gives the image of the relevant steps I'm taking:

```
// setup
private AudioTrack track[] = new AudioTrack[MAX_CHANNELS];

for( int i=0; i<MAX_CHANNELS; i++ ) {
        track[i] = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, SAMPLING_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, outBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        track[i].play();
}

// [...]
// -- RECEIVE THREAD --
DatagramPacket datagram = socket.receiveMessage();
// ... determine channel by ip
track[channel].write(datagram.getData(), datagram.getOffset(), datagram.getLength());
```

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing more of your design but as a general rule any delay over 200ms and any packet loss above 2-5% will impact a users received call quality. The easiest way to check the problem would be to print the audio buffer size out to logs and check to see if it is growing as you suspect.

Comment: The problem is actually that the buffer is growing too much, to the point I have hundreds of non-processed packets waiting there to be played...  I'm really lost.

Comment: If you can explain how you are doing the voice merging for the conference and/or share you code, it will make it easier to help. 'Merging' the audio is likely compute intensive and you are doing it on the phone itself, I think from your description, which may be at the root of the problem.

Comment: Edited the question with the mixing part, I am just actually using AudioTrack  now, but it doesn't seem to solve anything which puzzles me.  (And I also get white noise when chatting in 3 now, but that's another bug..)  thanks for the comments^^

Comment: I also tried splitting the process phase from the reception phase in 2 separate threads (with a blocking queue), which directly shows me that the queue eventually reaches its maximum capacity(100 packets), and then starts losing packets for a while, until it gets close enough to cope up, and this goes in circles.  I guess this is not the correct behavior at all, I wonder if I actually have to explicitly discard "late" packets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AudioTrack.write is blocking, you should make sure you have one thread for every channel you are writing to, so that write calls don't get stuck waiting for other channels to complete.